# Problem installing Ubuntu On Mbr disk Scheme not GPT

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu on my Mbr disk scheme with windows 7 already installed 
on UEFI Legacy mode but when trying to manual specify partition for installation i found 3 more partitions added automatically and the disk scheme converted to GPT Style and lost windows 7 which formatted by ubuntu I don't want GPT style at all. I have tried Ubuntu, ElementaryOS, Fedora latest distro all are the same. Is there any way installing Ubuntu like before with Mbr disk scheme without converting Disk to GPT style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you are installing Linux using UEFI mode, which will automatically convert the partition scheme to GPT, which is necessarry for UEFI.

If you want to keep Windows and Linux on legacy BIOS, simply make sure you are booting into the non-UEFI mode. Exactly how you do that depends on your motherboard. Normally when you get to select boot options, there will be listings that show UEFI options with `UEFI:` and non-UEFI options without.

Comment: Once you have converted to gpt, you many need to use fixparts to remove backup gpt partition table or gdisk to convert. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ Or gdisk: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Comment: If you convert to GPT, using FixParts to remove stray GPT data is pointless, and in fact FixParts will refuse to touch true GPT disks. `gdisk`, OTOH, is a GPT partitioning tool, and can be used to convert from MBR to GPT without data loss, if that's desired. Note that any OS booting from an MBR disk will require a new boot loader once the disk is converted to GPT mode.

Comment: it might be advisable to use UEFI if only to prevent future headaches.